# Newer version of MinGW doen't output function names into map-file

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw, mingw-w64

I've updated my MinGW-w64 installation, but when I try outputing a map-file (using '-Wl,-Map=output.map') the newer version doesn't output the names of the functions. Please take a look at the output fragment:

```
// Old version
0x00000000004027e8       0x24 C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\main.exe.ztAfDe.ltrans0.ltrans.o
0x00000000004027e8                FunctionName

// Newer version
0x00000000004027e8       0x24 C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\main.exe.ztAfDe.ltrans0.ltrans.o
```

Is there something I can do about it or do I have to stick with the older version of MinGW? Maybe I'm missing some additional flags or something? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "newer version", can you be more precise?
The latest version is available as standalone build from http://winlibs.com/
Can you try with that version? You can unzip it somewhere else without removing your other version.

Comment: Actually I'm updating exactly to the latest winlibs.com's (gcc 10.2) build from I believe musl.cc's build (gcc 9.3). So the latest winlibs.com's build (that includes Clang) linker not telling me the function names.

Comment: Do you have some example code I could try this with?
winlibs.com just provides a Windows build of the original sources, if this behaviour changed in GCC itself you should ask the GCC developers.

Comment: I think this only happens if you use `-flto`.